# Declared variable in Backbone.js View's render method seems not to exist?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application

When I instantiate a view object just like this:

```
app.MyCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#my-element",
  template: _.template($(#my-view-template).html()),

  render: function(){
    this.$el.append(this.template({
      "myTemplateVar": this.html_string
    }));
    var html_string = "<p>Some stuff here</p>";
  }
});
```

the variable "html_string" does not come into effect. The view will be rendered with an empty "myTemplateVar". However, if I declare "html_string" as a view parameter, everything works fine. What's wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fixed code:

```
app.MyCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#my-element",
    template: _.template($('#my-view-template').html()),

    render: function(){
        var html_string = "<p>Some stuff here</p>";

        this.$el.append(this.template({
            "myTemplateVar": html_string
        }));   
    }
});
```

1. You have an error in selector argument in the setting template method
2. You should declare variable and set it's value **before** passing it to the object
3. Yon have to call variable without `this.`

---

#### Short explanation

```
this.$el.append(this.template({
  "myTemplateVar": this.html_string
}));
```

In this code `this` in `this.html_string` refers to the object you're passing to the `this.template` method.

Answer (score 2):

When the function is called, `this` is set to the view. Your `html_string` variable is a property of the render function, not the view.